# Angular 2 is not updating the UI when making changes to a variable/model in Node

Tags: node.js, angular

I am currently using Angular 2 with Electron (which is basically using Node and web technologies to create a GUI).

All I want to do is list the files of the current directory.

Unfortunately, the variable "this.files" does not seem to update the data shown on the UI. Surprisingly however, when I click the dummy button thats linked to an empty method, it suddenly update. How do I fix this issue and whats the problem?

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
const fs = require('fs');

@Component(<any>{
    selector: 'files',
    template: `
<h2>Files</h2>

<ul *ngFor="let file of files">
    <li>{{ file }}</li>
</ul>

<button (click)="showFiles">Show Files</button>
`,
})
export class FilesComponent {
    files: any[];
    cwd: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cwd = __dirname;
        this.files = [];
        this.loadFiles();
    }

    loadFiles() {
        fs.readdir(this.cwd, (err, dir) => {
            for (let filePath of dir) {
                console.log(filePath);
                this.files.push(filePath);
            }
        });
    }

    showFiles() {
        // Empty method
        // Shows the files for some reason despite nothing happening
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `showFiles()` do?

Comment: literally nothing in the code. But for some reason the UI shows all the files when I click it.

Comment: Regarding why it works when you click: click events are monkey-patched by Angular's zone, so all of your template data bindings are checked after the click event handler runs.  Since `files` changed since the last check, the view is updated.  I don't know how Electron works, but as @Günter already answered, async events in Node.js are likely not monkey-patched, so Angular change detection is not triggered when the `readdir` callback runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably caused by `fs.readdir`. It seems it is using an API that is not patched by Angulars zone. To work around you can use

```
export class FilesComponent {
   constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

   loadFiles() {
     fs.readdir(this.cwd, (err, dir) => {
        for (let filePath of dir) {
            console.log(filePath);
            this.files.push(filePath);
        }
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail. I have never seen the `ChangeDetectorRef` before. A link would be helpful. However this has solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YahyaUddin,  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option for you as the accepted answer didn't work for my use case... basically `fs` runs outside of the Angular zone so you need to assign the variable inside of ngZone.

**NOTE:**  You may not actually need to run change detection manually depending on your use case.

```
import {Component, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
const fs = require('fs');

@Component(<any>{
    selector: 'files',
    template: `
<h2>Files</h2>

<ul *ngFor="let file of files">
    <li>{{ file }}</li>
</ul>

<button (click)="showFiles">Show Files</button>
`,
})
export class FilesComponent {
    files: any[];
    cwd: string;

    constructor(
      private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
      private zone: NgZone
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cwd = __dirname;
        this.files = [];
        this.loadFiles();
    }

    loadFiles() {
        fs.readdir(this.cwd, (err, dir) => {
            var newFiles = [];
            for (let filePath of dir) {
                console.log(filePath);
                newfiles.push(filePath);
            }
            this.zone.run(() => {
              this.files = newFiles;
              // NOTE: you may be able to delete this next line depending on your use case
              this.cd.detectChanges();
            })
        });
    }

    showFiles() {
        // Empty method
        // Shows the files for some reason despite nothing happening
    }
}
```