# Angular2 Observable not binding correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm working on implementing a search functionality via Angular2/TypeScript.

I'm having some trouble binding the search items returned to the view however.

My component is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../services/search.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: './app/views/search.component.html',
  providers: [SearchService]
})

export class SearchComponent {
  items: Observable<string[]>;
  errorMsg: string;

  private searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();

  searchConfluence(term : string) {
    // Send the search term into the Observable stream
    this.searchTermStream.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.searchTermStream
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.titleSearch(term));
  }

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {}
}
```

My view is the following:

```
<h1>Search</h1>
<input #term (keyup)="searchConfluence(term.value)" />
<ul style="list-style: none">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

My search service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  private searchUrl = URL_HERE;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  titleSearch(params: string): Observable<string[]> {
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header});
    let requestString = `term=${params}`;
    return this.http.get(`${this.searchUrl}?${requestString}`, options)
      .map(this.getData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private getData(resp: Response) {
    let body = resp.json();
    console.log(body.results);
    return body.results || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

The response returned by the server is following:

```
 [Object, Object ... ]
```

where each `Object` is a JSON object. This is what I'm expecting as a response.

I've checked the network trace and the HTTP request is firing to the correct place and I'm getting results back as well (again, all viewed through the network trace). I'm unable to view the any results in my view (the list just doesn't appear at all).

EDIT: One last edit, but I might have left out a crucial detail; my Angular2 application isn't inside a typical browser, but actually contained within an ElectronJS application. I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: could you please add `SearchService` service code as well?

Comment: Code seems perfect, it should work.. may be something related data retrieved from API isn't correctly binded.. any error in console?

Comment: please update response object in question..

Comment: Nope, there are no errors in the console, everything is just blank. I'm not sure what you mean by 'response object'. Its a JSON array that gets returned from the server.

Comment: Yes, please add that..

Comment: What do you get for `<div>{{items | async | json}}</div>`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nothing appears when I do that.

Comment: What do you get for `this.searchTermStream
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.titleSearch(term)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));`?

Comment: I get the JSON array that I'm expecting (i.e `[Object Object Object ...]`). For some reason it's not being bound to the `this.items` Observable.

Comment: You state that your server-response is an array, but you try to map to `return body.results || []` - is it possible that `results` does not exist here? Have you tried this yet: `return body || []`?

Comment: Yup I've tried that; following @GünterZöchbauer's comment above, if I use `console.log(val)` in the subscribe call, I'm getting the correct array from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day of just fiddling around, I got the answer to this question.

It looks like Electron's API doesn't update as quickly as a web browser does so I followed the solution found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130147/angular-2-is-not-updating-the-ui-when-making-changes-to-a-variable-model-in-node).

Basically I'm doing this in my `search.component.ts` class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.searchTermStream
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(term => this.searchService.titleSearch(term))
    .subscribe((result) => { 
      this.items = result;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

And voila, everything is updating correctly, and I have a nice list of my search results :).